# variable changes unexpectedly when awk or sed is in the script

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk

In the following script the value of variable `LINES` changes unexpectedly to value 24. But when I comment out the `awk` and `sed` commands, the rest work fine.

```
LINES=4
SNAPNUM=0

while [ $LINES -gt 0 ]
do
OUTPUT=$(ls -1 snapshot_com.crd.* | tail -$LINES | head -1)
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^trajin/) print $0, "'$OUTPUT'"; else print $0}' temp.trajin
sed '/^trajin/ s/$/ '$OUTPUT'/' temp.trajin > combine.trajin
((SNAPNUM++))
  printf "snapshot number $SNAPNUM\n"
  printf "line number $LINES\n"
 ((LINES--))
done
```

Comment: Your variable name is conflicting with a variable `LINES` used by the terminal: see [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is not directly related to `sed` or `awk` - it's a result of your choice of `LINES` as the name for your loop variable (and the scoping rules for shell variables).

The shell variables `LINES` and `COLUMNS` are used by terminal emulators to keep track of the size of their output window, so that they can correctly wrap text and paginate it (when a pager such as `less` is  being used). The default behavior of `bash` is to check the window size after each external command:

```
       checkwinsize
               If set, bash checks the window size after  each  command
               and,  if necessary, updates the values of LINES and COL‐
               UMNS.
```

In your case, `LINES` is getting updated (and reset to the default terminal height, which is 24 lines) after each invocation of `sed` and `awk`.

Although it's possible to turn off the `checkwinsize` option (using `shopt -u checkwinsize`) it's not recommended: instead you should simply change your variable name to something that won't conflict, such as lower-case `lines`. A good rule of thumb is to avoid all-upper-case names entirely: see for example [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts)